# what does connected(00000005) and verify return:1 in openssl s_client command

Tags: openssl

I am trying to test icinga2 client and server connectivity with openssl command and I am using a command like following line in client

```
openssl s_client -CAfile /var/lib/icinga2/certs/ca.crt  -cert  /var/lib/icinga2/certs/<client>.crt -key  /var/lib/icinga2/client.key  -connect icinga_server.domain.com:5665
```

and I am getting an output like

```
CONNECTED(00000005)
depth=1 CN = Icinga CA
verify return:1
depth=0 CN = icinga_server.domain.com
verify return:1
```

My question is what does **CONNECTED(00000005)** and **verify return:1** means ?

It must be CONNECTED(00000003) according to icinga2 documentation. I do not know what is the difference between CONNECTED(00000005) and CONNECTED(00000003)

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The number after the "CONNECTED" string is the file descriptor of the opened socket (as returned by the `socket()` system call), so you can safely ignore it. "verify return:1" means that the certificate is OK.